# How to make a c++ project from command prompt?

Tags: c++, command-line, command-prompt, setup-project

Note that this is referred to **make** a project from command prompt, not build or run it, by "make", i mean, creating a *.vcxproj* file like Visual Studio does.

I am unable to use Visual Studio for now, this is why i'm asking to make a project through cmd, i tried gcc, but it doesn't generate these project stuff.

Comment: Why do you want to make a Visual Studio project at a time when you cannot use Visual Studio? (There are other formats for project files, some of which were designed to be invoked from the command prompt.)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nmake-reference?view=msvc-160

Comment: @JaMiT my programming pc is under fixes, so i use one which is not as efficient (and lags very oftenly with vscode) just to keep coding.

Comment: AFAIK it's tricky and/or impractical to use `.vcxproj` projects with GCC. Rather than trying to shoehorn it, you can take this as an opportunity to learn how things are done in *nix/MinGW world: try using Make or CMake or some other build system.

Comment: @RafaelplayerxdYT If your not-as-efficient PC does not have VS installed, there is not really a benefit to creating a project file for VS until your programming PC is fixed (at which point, you can make it through VS as normal). Your question probably should have said "i mean, creating **something comparable to** a .vcxproj file like Visual Studio does" instead of specifying that you want the VS-specific format. *In fact, it would be even better if your question specified your goal instead of [the approach you assumed would fix your real issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC is just a compiler, rather than a full IDE like Visual Studio. It takes source code (and some binary libraries), and then outputs compiled executables or object files.

You can use a build system like [CMake](https://cmake.org/) or [Meson](https://mesonbuild.com/), which can make the building process easier for you and those who clone your code, and can even be integrated into Visual Studio. You can actually use CMake to convert projects into Visual Studio format.

Answer (score 1):

The `vcxproj` format provides information the MSBuild tool to control the build process. It's an XML file that is automatically created by Visual Studio, but its possible to make it manually by writing the XML yourself, and then specifying the file when invoking MSBuild from the cmd prompt.

See [this walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-using-msbuild-to-create-a-visual-cpp-project?view=msvc-160) in the MS docs, and [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcxproj-file-structure?view=msvc-160) to the vcxproj format if you want it to work when you regain access to VS.

Alternatively, if you're not absolutely required to use Visual Studio and the Visual C++ ecosystem, then it might be worth exploring other build systems as suggested in other answers/comments.

Comment: Sure, but creating one by myself seems like a lot of work, also, i am kinda required to use the Visual C++ because i am trying to use some features that are unknown to me if other methods are used, like adding project references.

Comment: @RafaelplayerxdYT *"but creating one by myself seems like a lot of work, also,"* -- Well, that is what you asked for. You did not ask "How to make a c++ project from command prompt unless it involves a lot of work?" You dropped the primary tool (VS) for creating VS-specific files, so moderate to a lot of work should be expected.